# Querystring truncate string after "#"

Tags: c#, query-string

### Updated

Looks like if folder name string contains "#" it is getting truncated in the querystring itself , i tried below but both gives me only Junli Zhuang instead of 
Junli Zhuang # Kangna Zeng

```
 Request.Url.Query
 Request.Querystring
```

Junli Zhuang # Kangna Zeng

code=VST5ic61HC2UhAFGBLCzp0OF5x3V4WLZMdjRH%2blY1iKVhBeHE9qwI8X%2bPGQ1fYlg0eW3VHhLu9tvUqrInf8hHQffk%2fr7IShrs70DM5ManybKon%2bjz5RTzx8vl10Yo5ahimFoecxA%2b8DAWOPUvlt%2blsDy1WXU0Yfft6ENeG%2bmX27Kj80BOfMR7J0x5oWpNXfWjj1RRPXNkFXOpPn3dfaSIMWb%2fbdN%2fjmwj5APwsw5uRA%3d&ow=False&`fp=%2f4.+Junli+Zhuang`

---

Resolved -

I have query string which looks like below -

code=VST5ic61HC2UhAFGBLCzp0OF5x3V4WLZMdjRH%2blY1iKVhBeHE9qwI8X%2bPGQ1fYlg0eW3VHhLu9tvUqrInf8hHQffk%2fr7IShrs70DM5ManybKon%2bjz5RTzx8vl10Yo5ahimFoecxA%2b8DAWOPUvlt%2blsDy1WXU0Yfft6ENeG%2bmX27Kj80BOfMR7J0x5oWpNXfWjj1RRPXNkFXOpPn3dfaSIMWb%2fbdN%2fjmwj5APwsw5uRA%3d&ow=False&`fp=%2f4.+Junli+Zhuang+&+Kangna+Zeng`

```
I am reading the value of "fp" like below -
 string uploadDirectoryStructure = context.Request.QueryString["fp"].ToString()

it gives me - 4. Junli Zhuang 

but if you look at querystring it should give me - 4. Junli Zhuang & Kangna Zeng

I tried using like this but it did not help -

 string uploadDirectoryStructure = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.QueryString["fp"].ToString())
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control of the application that is generating the query string?
If it is generated on a web page, you can use encodeURIComponent() on it like so via javascript that will encode the & symbol.

```
encodeURIComponent("Junli+Zhuang+&+Kangna+Zen");
```

Otherwise, if it is out of your control, then you can use Request.Url.Query in your controller action, and the process the string manually to get everything after fp

```
 var startSegment = "&fp";
 var result = Request.Url.Query.Substring(myString.IndexOf(startSegment) + startSegment.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input query string is incorrect. The symbol `&` should be URL encoded to `%26`. Otherwise it indicates the next pair in the query string.